# Copy Python project to other computer

Tags: python, pycharm, project, interpreter

When I copy my project (with flash driver) from one computer to another, and try to run the project in the second computer in the pycharm it says - Error running 'file.py': Cannot run program + "The path of the interpreter that I had in my first computer". How does it know the path of the interpreter that I had in the first computer and why does it search for it? Maybe somewhere in the project it saves the interpreter?
In some files it succeed to run.
I Changed the interpreter and it still searching for the interpreter that I had in the first computer and from that reason I can't run the project from the other computer.
I tried also to change the working directory and still it throws the exception "No module named 'package_name'" when I run the program.

Comment: If you're including the `.idea` directory, the location of the interpreter is in there - it's part of the project settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to modify the `.idea/workspace.xml` file?